# Camera 'OK' button not functioning

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Hey guys I just added a feature for a user to be able to capture a picture from my app, and I have the camera intent setup properly [I believe so at least]. I setup a button in an 'xml' file and setup the intent and button accordingly in the 'class/java' file. When testing the app the button works and loads the native android 4.0.4 camera, and takes a picture fine, but when I click the 'checkmark' [The 'ok' button on older versions of Android] It doesn't return to the app. The camera still maintains all functionality it does not freeze up or anything. I can still choose to retake a picture, or choose to cancel; just the 'OK/checkmark' button doesn't work in any way.

---

```
public class XXXXXXXXXXX extends Activity 
{

    Button button;
    String path;
    boolean taken;

    static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.XXXXXXXX);

        button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.take_picture );
        button.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler() );
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images/testing-cam.jpg";

    }


    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener 
        {
            public void onClick( View view )
            {
                Log.i("Button", ".onClick()" );
                startCameraActivity();
            }
        }

        protected void startCameraActivity()
        {
            Log.i("Start", "CameraActivity()" );
            File file = new File( _path );
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
            intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

            startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
        }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    switch( resultCode )
    {
        case 0:
            break;

        case -1:
            onPhotoTaken();
            break;
    }
}

protected void onPhotoTaken()
{
    taken = true;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );

    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    field.setVisibility( View.GONE );
}
```

---

If any other code is needed I can provide it, but this is the main camera code I have used in my app.

Comment: Do you have an OnActivityResult() method in your activity? If so post that please

Comment: Add some Log statements to the OnActivityResult method to see if the camera is ever returning control to there or not.

Answer (score 6):

Have you used this in Mainfest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

you can follow this links also.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html

Comment: Yes all of those are in manifest! Thanks for the link, I'm checking into it now.

Comment: If it helps then up the answer too

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to create directory you write image.
Add this line before you create file object.

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/images/").
path.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use my complete code for your solution.this is the link:-[Imp Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414463/launch-android-camera-intent-and-layout/13414940#13414940).