# launch android camera intent and layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to load the camera to take a photo from my android app,

**my Photos.java is**

```
private Uri imageUri;

public void takePhoto(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                 bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                 .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

and this works great. But its the layout section to call this intent which I am struggling with.

I created a button to load the camera

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/takePhoto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:onClick="takePhoto"
    android:text="@string/Photos_Button1" />
```

but now I need to have a section to show the image I have taken. How do I do that?

Comment: I am also getting errors where the code includes "TAKE_PICTURE" saying cannon be resolved to a variable... and then with "ImageView" saying cannon be resolved or is not a field

Thanks

Henry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Give this a try...**

*NOTE : Only applicable to Android API 8 // 2.2 or higher*

```
public class PhotoActivity extends Activity {

    /** The Constant PICK_IMAGE. */
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 0;

    /** The Constant PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY. */
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY = 1;

    /** The btn cancel. */
    private Button btnPhotoCamera,btnPhotoGallery,btnCancel;

    /** The img view. */
    private ImageView imgView;

    /** The u. */
    private Uri u;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_options);

        imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgDisplayImage);
        btnPhotoCamera=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoCamera);
        btnPhotoGallery=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoGallery);
        btnCancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

        btnPhotoCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent camera=new Intent();
                camera.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                camera.putExtra("crop", "true");

                File f=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

                u = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"myFile.jpg"));
                camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, u);
                startActivityForResult(camera, PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        btnPhotoGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
            }
        });

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent goStartUp=new Intent(PhotoActivity.this, StartUpActivity.class);
                goStartUp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(goStartUp);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (resultCode==RESULT_OK )
        {
            if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {

                InputStream is=null;
                try {
                    is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(u);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                Log.i("Inside", "PICK_IMAGE");
            }

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Log.d("data",filePathColumn[0]);
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.i("Inside", "PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML File:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSelectOptions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/two_options"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPhotoCamera"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblSelectOptions"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/camera"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPhotoGallery"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnPhotoCamera"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/gallery"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnPhotoGallery"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDisplayImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/below_this_text_image_will_be_displayed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="13dp"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblDisplayImage"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <!--
             <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgDisplayImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblDisplayImage"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/area_where_image_is_to_be_displayed" />
        <!-- </ScrollView> -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ALso Modify the Android Manifest file as per your use with following:-

```
<manifest....
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
<application....
..........
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: File f=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

                u = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"myFile.jpg"));

Comment: I have used it and have successfully executed this.I am not able to figure out why you are getting that issue

Comment: could you help me by explaining the purpose of those two lines? I might be able to figure out whats wrong in this case. Thanks

Comment: sorted... `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` only works in API 8 (Android 2.2) or newer... I was using 7 // 2.1 :)

Comment: Removed       `camera.putExtra("crop", "true");` as it is not a fully acceptible inetent method.

Answer (score -2):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Photos_Text1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/takePhoto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="takePhoto"
    android:text="@string/Photos_Button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pagePhotoUpload"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="pagePhotoUpload"
    android:text="@string/Photos_Button2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.85"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I was using

```
     android:onClick="takePhoto"
```

however this was not devined in my java anywhere, I had fabricated "takePhoto"