# display picture in imageview photo taken by camera in android

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a problem in Android development with camera. i try to take a pic and display it in to imageview but the result does not show but it works fine for Galaxy Note but i doesnt work for Galaxy S3

My Code is Bellow

Camera Activity

```
package com.nfs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Camera extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 500;
    private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    this.imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLoad);
    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btCam);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);                         

        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
```

}

layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Click Here" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLoad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is there any exception? are you able to get the bitmap from intent in `onActivityResult` method...

Comment: Nop there are no exceptions and the image display foe one second and disappears

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        final Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                try {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    bmpSelectedImage = getThumbnail(selectedImage);

                    set_img_camera.setImageBitmap(bmpSelectedImage);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("image error", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try my Code which is working fine.I suppose this will solve your Problem.The link is as follows:-[Imp Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414463/launch-android-camera-intent-and-layout/13414940#13414940).